# android.os.TransactionTooLargeException - binder buffer

Tags: android, performance

I am using Parcelable classes to pass data between Activities. As the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/TransactionTooLargeException.html) suggests, I keep all transactions relatively small (100kb) because the Binder transaction buffer has 1Mb capacity. The problem is that if I repeat a small transaction many times the buffer reach that size and the os throws **android.os.TransactionTooLargeException**.

My feeling is that the buffer isn't promptly set free between transactions. Is there a way to check the binder buffer size?

Comment: "I repeat a small transaction" -- what does this mean? What is a "transaction"? How do you "repeat" it?

Comment: Not sure about the scope of a transaction but what I mean is that if I iterate passing the same amount of data between the activity A and B the buffer reaches the famous 1MB size... @CommonsWare

Comment: If the "Parcelable classes" are your own, perhaps there's a bug in one's parcel-ing logic.

Comment: By bug, I mean "bug". :-) For example, are you somehow parceling and de-parceling something that is a static value, that possibly is therefore growing over time?

Comment: @CommonsWare Haha - nope, no static properties, just simple classes with bunch of String and some Array...

Comment: If you can create a sample project that reproduces the error, I'd like to take a peek at it.

Comment: @CommonsWare I'll investigate a bit more and I'll get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: hi guys, did anybody find out how to check the binder buffer size available before a service call?? thanks :)

Comment: It's likely that the "transactions" are overlapping in some way. It's also possible that the transaction is larger than you expect. How are you calculating that size?